# javascript check null or empty string

Tags: javascript

Why is this not possible?

```html
var value = null;

if(value == (null || ""))
{
   //do something
}
```

I would like to check a value if it is null or empty without using the variable over and over again.

Comment: This is the way the language works. First of all, that expression in parentheses will evaluate to "", so it will check for that. That's how it works, and that's that.

Comment: why is it so bad to do `(value == null || value == "")` ??

Comment: which values or types are wanted? which not?

Answer (score 21):

Use `!value`. It works for `undefined`, `null` and even `''` value:

```js
var value = null;

if(!value)
{
  console.log('null value');
}

value = undefined;

if(!value)
{
  console.log('undefined value');
}

value = '';

if(!value)
{
  console.log('blank value');
}
```

Comment: And zero..... so may not be the best option based on the input

Comment: `javascript check null or empty string` OP says string value @epascarello

Comment: So when you have `value = '0';` then `!value` is `false`

Answer (score 1):

If we split the condition into its two relevant parts, you first have `null || ""`. The result of that will be equal to the empty string `""`.

Then you have `value == ""`., which will be `false` if `value` is `null`.

The correct way to write your condition is `value == null || value == ""`.